# All Updated Plugins Disappeared

Tags: plugins, updates

I had 5 plugins with updates. After updating all of them through the Available Updates tool they disappeared from the Network Plugins page. I received errors like this for all plugins:

```
The plugin custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
```

The folders still exist in /wp-content/plugins/

When I deleted the folders and uploaded them through FTP they do not appear on the Plugins page. When I install them through wp-admin I receive this log text:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/custom-post-type-ui.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Installing the plugin…
Successfully installed the plugin Custom Post Type UI 0.7.1.
Network Activate | Return to Plugin Installer
```

But when I click Network Activate, I receive this error:

```
The plugin does not have a valid header.
```

This happens for all 5 plugins and only happened beginning today.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, seemed to come out of the blue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, still no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved this issue by removing re-uploading the admin and includes folders, although I'm not sure what originally caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error `The plugin does not have a valid header.`  you need to check your plugins file, there might be some white space before or after `<?php` and `?>`

Remove those spaces, then the error `The plugin does not have a valid header.` wont display